# File lock kept opened even after closing the file, co-editing gone for toss in my Enterprise

Tags: macos, mojave, ms-office, smb, ntfs

The latest macOS 10.14.x and macOS 10.15.x have degraded their behavior with Word applications on network drives mapped via SMB. These network drives are shared drives on the Windows 2019 file server or it can be on any Linux file server.

Issues:

A) When we map an n/w drive on macOS 10.14.x and above versions with SMB and open a .docx file and close it, the file lock is not released by the client even after closing/force-existing the application on the client. This takes a toll on our n/w users who are working on co-editing the file for various needs of my enterprise. Thorough testing has revealed that this issue is not seen on  macOS 10.12/10.13.

We can reconfirm this issue by listing the files opened on n/w drive on Windows 2019 file server's PowerShell command "Get-SmbOpenFile", we will continue to see the file lock from client even after closing/force-exiting the file/application from client.

Anyone heard/observed this issue?

Are there any posts/fixes about this behavior that Apple introduced from  macOS 10.14? This is really degrading Mac usability and corrupting n/w users data  and making lives of shared drive administrators difficult!

Comment: Are you *sure* this is not behavior introduced in recent version of Office for the Mac rather than macOS itself?

Comment: Hi Steve,

Yes, I am very much certain that this issue is from MAC10.14 and not introduced from Office version.

Have tried Office2011/2016/2019 on MAC10.12, and 10.13, and 10.14 - everything points finger @ MAC OS 10.14